# CSS: font-family in body doesn't apply to content

Tags: html, css, font-family

I'm using google font api, this code works when I move the font-family line into encapsulated classes and ids, Why is it that I have to move my font-family line into .banner for it to affect text inside my banner class

css:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Crimson Text';
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px;


    .banner {
        otherstuff
    }

}
```

html.erb:

```
<div class="banner">
    <%= image_tag("logo.png")%>
    <div class="login_menu_bar">
        <label>login</label>
        <label>password</label>
        </br>
        yeah
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the CSS above should be something like this?

```
body{
    font-family: 'Crimson Text';
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.banner {
    otherstuff
}
```

Comment: didn't make a difference to what I can see, shouldn't the font-family specified in body apply to all child elements inside the <body>?

Comment: It does, your syntax is just wrong. There is no such thing as nested curly braces in CSS. Body refers to the whole page excluding the header. So it need not to be explicitly declared on sub elements styles.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that, but there's something funky going on here. I'll work it out.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/QCYVs/